# Solving 'BadRequestException' while using Confluence API to include <hr> and other HTML tags in page creation/update

Tags: confluence-rest-api

When creating a new confluence page (or updating an existing one) I find that certain html tags cause a 400 error with a message "message":"com.atlassian.confluence.api.service.exceptions.BadRequestException: Content body cannot be converted to new editor format". I can pass

, <h1..6>,  with no issue, but a horizontal line break

---

will error and cause the create / update to fail.

Searching through the Atlassian Documentation I was expecting to find either

1. a way to pass markdown / markup that enables some of these formatting features, just as I can if I directly edit a page
2. a list of dissallowed html tags

I could find neither

Comment: Have you tried to add a forward slash (/) to these tags ? For example `<hr/>` should work where `<hr>` will raise an error.